# Please welcome your new moderator, Stéphane Gimenez!

Tags: discussion, moderation

After distinguished service, [F'x](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/19/fx) has stepped down as one of your moderators to tackle his very busy schedule. Joining the ranks of the team to help lead the French Stack Exchange Community is Stéphane Gimenez:

[image: profile for Stéphane Gimenez at French Language & Usage Stack Exchange, Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language]

Stéphane has an unrelenting history of guiding users in this community to get the most out of French Stack Exchange, and can now continue this work in a much greater capacity. Please welcome Stéphane as he takes his post and joins the ranks of your incredibly talented moderation team!

Answer (score 14):

I'm stepping in as moderator pro-tempore, but I must say that I've always been  satisfied with my simple user status.
The StackExchange model is so neat as to include everyone in the moderation process.
I accepted the vacant position to help Gilles and Evpok in performing the 'special ops' in a timely manner but I'm also looking forward to seeing more of us involved in the prosperity of this community!

All the best to F'x for the days to come. We hope to see you around now and then.

And keep going everyone!

---

J'accepte le rôle de modérateur pro-tempore, mais pour autant le statut de simple utilisateur m'a jusque là très bien convenu. Le modèle de StackExchange est bien pensé et permet de faire participer l'ensemble de la communauté au processus de modération.
Si j'ai accepté le poste de modérateur vacant pour aider Gilles et Evpok dans les cas qui nécessitent une intervention spéciale, j'espère surtout qu'un maximum d'entre nous continueront à faire prospérer le site !

Amitiés à F'x, on espère te voir par ici de temps en temps.

Et en avant toutes !

Comment: You do a lot of community moderation and I feel that you deserve this role.  I am curious as to when we are going to have an election for mods though.

Comment: @Patrick: See here http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/327/duree-de-la-beta-duration-of-the-beta :-)

Comment: Congrats Stéphane, you truly deserve it, having been one of the truly helpful users since the very beginning, and continuing to be. And you're right, most of the work should be done by regular users anyway

Comment: Excellent choice. It's quite obvious for regular users that you already fulfilled a mod role well before that. And we'll indeed go on trying to help as much as we can.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks everyone for the nice time here! I won't have time to help the mod team, and probably will not be able to visit regularly. But I really loved being part of the nice community building the site, and wish you all the very best for the future!

Comment: Thanks F'x! Good luck with stuffs